# How to read multi-word input into one String?

Tags: java

How do I read user inputs, one line at a time to create an object. Which then goes into a ArrayList? As you can see, when I enter the name, it's breaks it up and only stores the last name. Or if I do: first-middle-last name, it stores the middle and last name.

I enter the name the first time, which calls the search method first, to see if the name already exists in the ArrayList. That works fine. And if the name isn't in the list, the search returns null. Which then prompts the inputs and add method.

```
case 1: {
            System.out.print("Enter the Students name: ");
            String nameSearch = kbd.next();
            Student stu = dc.search(nameSearch );
            if (stu != null) {
                System.out.println(stu); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Enter name AGAIN: ");
                String nameAdd= kbd.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Enter grade (freshman, sophomore, junior, senior: ");
                String categoryAdd = kbd.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Major: ");
                String majorAdd = kbd.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Enter graduating year: ");
                int yearAdd = kbd.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter student ID: (xxxx.xxxx: ");
                double idAdd= kbd.nextDouble();

                dc.add(nameAdd, categoryAdd , majorAdd , 
                        yearAdd , idAdd);
            }
            break;
        }
```

My input:

```
Enter the Students name: John Smith
Not Found(Search Method)
TEST
Enter name AGAIN: TEST2
Enter grade (freshman, sophomore, junior, senior: senior
Major: Computer Science
Enter graduating year: 2013
Enter student ID: 1234.4567
```

How it's stored inside the object when I print ArrayList:

```
Name: Smith
Grade: senior
Major: Computer Science
Graduating Year: 2013
Student ID: 1234.4567
```

The add method:

```
public Student add(String name, String grade,
        String major, int year, double id) {
    Student newStu = new Student(addName, addGrade, addMajor, addYear, addId);
    studentList.add(newStu );
    System.out.println("Added!");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is kbd? Its not clear from question

Comment: @loki Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Why bother specifying that you're returning `Student` if you're only returning `null`?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
String nameSearch = kbd.next();
```

Should probably be

```
String nameSearch = kbd.nextLine();
```

right?

Comment: I tried that, but it activates my search method, which for some reason prints the first time in the ArrayList. I am 99% sure my search method isn't the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make **kbd** a **BufferedReader** (e.g. `BufferedReader kbd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`), then do this...

```
case 1: {
            System.out.print("Enter the Students name: ");
            String nameSearch = kbd.readLine();
            Student stu = dc.search(nameSearch );
            if (stu != null) {
                System.out.println(stu); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Enter name AGAIN: ");
                String nameAdd= kbd.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter grade (freshman, sophomore, junior, senior: ");
                String categoryAdd = kbd.readLine();

                System.out.print("Major: ");
                String majorAdd = kbd.readLine();

                System.out.print("Enter graduating year: ");
                int yearAdd = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());

                System.out.print("Enter student ID: (xxxx.xxxx: ");
                double idAdd= Double.parseDouble(kbd.readLine());

                dc.add(nameAdd, categoryAdd , majorAdd , 
                        yearAdd , idAdd);
            }
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `String nameSearch = kbd.nextLine();`. I read on the multiline java tutorial.
Hope this helps. In some way.